# Difference between Gapps

Tags: custom-roms, google-apps

What is the difference, if any, between different Gapps providers such as opengapps, tk gapps, pa gapps etc?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Open gapps is open source developed, all their code is available on github. PAGapps is developed by the Paranoid Android team. So there you have it. An app doesnt have to be created by google to work as a google app. Other developers also give you a choice as  to whether you want all or just one google app (gapp) The pico is just the play store, if I remember rightly. I no longer use any Gapps at all. I use a separate apk downloader called Raccoon with a throwaway google account.

Comment: I'm looking for the original sources behind your claim. Please provide them. For example, for open gapps, you can link their GitHub page. For PAGapps, there must be some XDA thread or official blog/site link.

Comment: Even with those links, I very much doubt e.g. the Playstore app coming with OpenGApps will be open-source. Quoting [their homepage](http://opengapps.org/): "The Open GApps Project is an ***open-source effort to script the automatic generation*** of up-to-date Google Apps packages." (emphasis mine). So it's just the *bundling* that makes the difference here, not the apps themselves.